# Must a listening socket runs in thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have some problems understanding how a socket should be handled. I get that server socket must runs in its own thread, because it must check if there are new connections. Now, i'm not sure if every socket opened by a new connection should runs in a thread.

What i have in mind is checking every x time the socket states. If it has something to be read, then read. If not, check the next socket. I see some examples where this process is done in a thread, but i dont want a socket to do stuff, just want to read if it has some data, and process them.

Comment: And if another bit of stuff comes in while you are processing that stuff, what happens?

Comment: What difference makes doing the reading in a different thread?

Comment: If you get that a listening socket must run in another thread, why is it the title of your question?

Comment: And what's the difference between 'do stuff' and 'read'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you don't need to listen in a separate thread.  But, just realize that while you are "listening" your entire program will be waiting for that to complete before moving onward.

So unless you are fine with your entire program waiting, I would suggest a separate thread.

Comment: Right now i use DataInputStream to check if there are some stuff to be read (input.available();), so the program should not wait. Am i right?

Comment: available should not block, so no it should not wait if you are just looping through and checking that method.  But it might block on the read (depending on how many bytes you try to read). It's also a bottleneck as you have one thread looping.  Data might be gathering in the other buffers while you are processing one.

Comment: And what's the matter with that? Imagine you have a game, and the server process input received from clients. But you dont want each connection to act independly, but retrieve the input and then process them (for example, if you use a component-system approach, do stuff on a different system). I fail to see why is needed to check the data at the moment.

Comment: It's not wrong, and in the case you mentioned it might be fine.  But for example maybe the threads could listen and do some processing on the input, then the main thread can do less processing and possibly more work.

Comment: Terminology please. It is the ServerSocket that is listening. The Sockets are read or written.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have one thread which communicates with all sockets in a round-robin manner. It checks each socket if it has new data, and when it hasn't it checks the next.

Another alternative is to use NIO (New Input/Output).

The idea behind NIO is that you have a thread with one [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) which owns multiple [Channels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channel.html) (a channel can be a network socket or any other IO interface). You then call [selector.select()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28%29) in a loop. This method blocks until one or more channels have data, and then returns a set of these channels. You can then process the data the channels delivered.

[Here is a tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/).

Answer (score 1):

The problems with round-robin using available() are many.

1. It assumes that available() actually works, which isn't guaranteed.
2. It assumes that all clients need the same amount of service.
3. N-1 clients wait while one client is serviced.
4. A non-responsive client can block not only your application but all the other clients.

I'm sure there are more.

Don't do this. Use threads or NIO.